# login with facebook React Native Feathersjs

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, facebook-login, feathersjs

I'd like to build a login with facebook feature using react native and Feathersjs. Feathersjs uses passportjs and NodeJS. So any strategies using the underlying technologies should work as well. I've been following this diagram but don't know how to do the user registration and return a jwt to the mobile app in feathers.

[image]

I can do the first two arrows. How do I implement (what do I expose and do) arrows 3-6?

Comment: https://medium.com/@jackzhang0096/how-to-setup-oauth-2-0-token-strategy-on-feathersjs-1d77cc32118b is written for Facebook but it should work the same for Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer as @Daff suggested is this article https://medium.com/@jackzhang0096/how-to-setup-oauth-2-0-token-strategy-on-feathersjs-1d77cc32118b except one should use https://github.com/drudge/passport-facebook-token

basic idea is you pass the api the access_token and the api speaks directly to facebook for extra info and creates a User account and returns a jwt token to the react native app.